# Multiple ExpressionEngine sites/installs on cloud server

Tags: multiple-sites, install

I have a simple question regarding the installation of multiple EE sites on a single cloud server: I have a basic LAMP stack (w/ Ubuntu 14.04) on my RackSpace server that runs several websites. The primary website is already running on EE, and I'm just wondering if I can install another instance of ExpressionEngine for a different site on the same server, without issue, assuming I create a separate MySQL database for the new site?

Thanks for any insight here.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea! Kind of...

If your RackSpace server functions essentially like a VPS or bare metal machine (just in the cloud), then you're all set! There are a couple way to go about it. I'll explain a couple of simple ways this works on a regular VPS or bare metal machine.

You have your web root and an EE installation working on it. One way to go is [Multi Site Manager](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/). This works well for multiple domains functioning from the same EE install. The instructions are relatively straight-forward.

If you want to keep these installations **completely** silo-ed, you can install a separate EE instance in a sub-folder of your web root:

```
/my-web-root/second-ee-site/
```

Then you just need to set up your VirtualHost (for Apache) settings for that new folder to match your new second-site domain, set your DNS entries for the new domain to point at your RackSpace server, and make sure you set your new EE install to have the right server paths (`/my-web-root/second-ee-site/` instead of `/my-web-root/`). I have a few EE sites that live in a sub-folder of my web-root, which is it's own EE site just like this.

If either of these methods applies to a RackSpace server... I don't know, since I don't have one. But again, if a RackSpace cloud server functions like a regular bare metal machine, just in the RackSpace cloud, you should be all set. I hope others chime in (or yourself) if I'm being particularly ignorant.

And oh, yes, you need a separate DB schema for each install. Well, you don't **need**, but trust me, you want.

Comment: thanks for the response! that all sounds good. Yes, the config is as you described, with the separate websites already configured in the `/var/www/vhosts` folder as `site-1.com` and `site-2.com`. The first is already set up as an EE site, and I'm thinking just to keep things simple, I'll just do a fresh install of EE in the other site folder, and set up a separate, corresponding database. I can't imagine there would be any conflicts that way?

Comment: Just one thing, if you have your second site in /webroot/ee-second-site/, going to first-site.com/ee-second-site, itll load your second site :p